# Is there difference "I will be with the patient until he is situated" and "I will be with the patient until he settles"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I watched a movie about a patient with cancer. Now she was in a serious situation and the father of the patient said to the doctor "**I will be with her until she is situated**". I asked myself why not "**until she settles**"

You are looking after a patient with a cancer.

Is there difference "**I will be with the patient until he is situated**" and "**I will be with the patient until he settles**"?

It seems that "**to be situated**" is more permanent and "**to settle**" is more temporary, right?

Comment: Please edit to tell more about the meaning you want. I suspect that you mean "The patient has been introduced to a new environment and needs to become accustomed to it and become comfortable," but I don't want to assume. For this, "*gets* situated" and "settles *in*" would be more idiomatic choices.

Comment: To be situated means to put in a particular place, to be settled means something different: it can mean "to establish a residence" or set up a more permanent home, or it can refer to being at rest and peaceful. This is in a dictionary, and when asking a question you should look up words in the dictionary and state in the question what you found.

Answer (score 1):

"**I will be with her until she is situated**" is a very odd phrase, although it may be usual amongst medical professionals. It can only mean until a (semi)permanent bed is found for her rather than until she settles or becpmes accustomed to her environment. You would definitely use "**until she settles**" or similar if you meant that. being "situated" in this sentance definitely implies an action that the patient is subject to.

Knowing which film would help as this may be American English, and also the script writer may not be using the language that would actually by used by a medical professional.